# How to prevent multiple childs to be created in MDI

Tags: delphi, mdi

How to prevent a child from being creating multiple times,
ex: a login form. 
Is there a solution without looping over the childs before the login form is getting opened and check if another instance of it is created.

Comment: Forms don't get created by accident. You create them. So, you can choose not to.

Comment: Yes, and i'm wondering how to prevent the user from doing that .. maybe there is like an option for "Multi Forms" or something

Comment: You were the one that gave them power to create forms. It's your code that creates them.

Comment: and how can i give them the power to open only one form at a time?

Comment: Count how many forms you create. Refuse to do it if that number equals one. Also, why put log in form in an MDI child? Ought to be modal dialogue surely?

Comment: `TForm` has a `MDIChildCount` property, you don't have to cound the Forms manually, unless you are only interested in specific types of child Forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, each Form has a global pointer declared. Even if you don't auto-create the Forms, you can still utilize that pointer. For any give Form, initialize its global pointer to `nil` at startup, check the pointer for `nil` before creating a new instance of that Form, destroy the Form when it is closed, and reset its global pointer back to `nil` when the Form is destroyed.  For example:

```
unit LoginForm;

interface

...

type
  TLoginForm = class(TForm)
    ...
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    ...
  end;

var
  LoginForm: TLoginForm = nil; // <-- here

implementation

...

procedure TLoginForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;

procedure TLoginForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoginForm := nil;
end;

...

end.
```

```
procedure TMainForm.SomeProcedure;
begin
  ...
  if not Assigned(LoginForm) then
    LoginForm := TLoginForm.Create(Self);
  LoginForm.Show;
  ...
end;
```